# -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000002

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, unrecognized-selector, nscfnumber

I knew there are lots of same kind of question available but I am facing something different. I got this error while saving the data into core data. First let me tell you my scenario. I am calling an API and store it into database. There is no issue but for lazy loading when I am calling the same API (for the next dataset) and when I try to again push it to database each and every time I am getting this error and application crashed. Even I have tried with some static data but in second case it crash.

**ActivityViewController**

```
func loadActivity() {
    CISyncManager.sharedManager().pullActivity(complition: { (activities) -> () in
       CILocalStorageManager.sharedManager().storeActivity(activities, complition: { (success, error) -> () in
           // other stuffs
        })
    })
}

func loadMoreActivity(lastId: String) {
    CISyncManager.sharedManager().pullActivity(lastId: lastId complition: { (activities) -> () in
       CILocalStorageManager.sharedManager().storeActivity(activities, complition: { (success, error) -> () in
           // other stuffs
        })
    })
}
```

**CILocalStorageManager**

```
func storeActivity(activities: [AnyObject], complition:((success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> ())?) {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.CILSM.activity", nil)
    for object in activities {
        dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
            //design the context with `object`
            self.saveChanges()
        })
    }

    if complition != nil {
        complition!(success: true, error: nil)
    }
}

func saveChanges() {
    if !CIDataManager.sharedManager().managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        return
    }

    CIDataManager.sharedManager().managedObjectContext.performBlock { () -> Void in
        do {
            try CIDataManager.sharedManager().managedObjectContext.save()
            print("save")
        } catch {
            print("Error : \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Crash Log**

```
2016-03-30 13:43:14.323 MyApp[2703:66401] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000002
2016-03-30 13:43:27.714 MyApp[2703:66401] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000002 with userInfo (null)
2016-03-30 13:43:31.958 MyApp[2703:66401] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000002'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bfde65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105534deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c0648d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b5390a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b534b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ad5dfa CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 202
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001021a1e37 -[NSString compare:options:range:] + 29
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010222d3bd -[NSComparisonPredicateOperator performPrimitiveOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 365
    8   Foundation                          0x00000001021fb719 -[NSPredicateOperator performOperationUsingObject:andObject:] + 286
    9   Foundation                          0x00000001021fae3c -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 313
    10  CoreData                            0x0000000104a1f931 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _objectInResults:] + 97
    11  CoreData                            0x0000000104a1fb09 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _preprocessInsertedObjects:insertsInfo:newSectionNames:] + 265
    12  CoreData                            0x0000000104a21dc6 __77-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 1366
    13  CoreData                            0x00000001049348a7 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 199
    14  CoreData                            0x000000010493476e -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 222
    15  CoreData                            0x0000000104a21857 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 119
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bca69c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bca3db _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bca142 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c0f972 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1986
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ac5279 _CFXNotificationPost + 633
    21  Foundation                          0x0000000102199109 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    22  CoreData                            0x000000010491a606 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 70
    23  CoreData                            0x000000010491a58a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:] + 1530
    24  CoreData                            0x0000000104914a0b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 3147
    25  CoreData                            0x0000000104918444 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 148
    26  MyApp                          0x0000000100f06a29 _TFC10MyApp21CILocalStorageManager11saveChangesfS0_FT_T_ + 217
    27  MyApp                          0x0000000100f06d12 _TToFC10MyApp21CILocalStorageManager11saveChangesfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    28  MyApp                          0x0000000100f037b0 _TFC10MyApp21CILocalStorageManager17storeHomeActivityfS0_FTCSo7NSArray10complitionGSqFT7successSb5errorGSqCSo7NSError__T___T_ + 384
    29  MyApp                          0x0000000100f03a34 _TToFC10MyApp21CILocalStorageManager17storeHomeActivityfS0_FTCSo7NSArray10complitionGSqFT7successSb5errorGSqCSo7NSError__T___T_ + 260
    30  MyApp                          0x0000000100eea766 _TFFFC10MyApp13CIDataManager25requestToLoadHomeActivityFS0_FT24requestToLoadNewActivitySb10completionGSqFT_T__5errorGSqFT9errorTypeOS_9ErrorType7messageGSqSS__T___T_U_FCSo7NSArrayT_U_FT_T_ + 502
    31  MyApp                          0x0000000100ea1f27 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 39
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010690ee5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010692f49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001069172af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b5dd09 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b1f2c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b1e828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001083b6ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    39  UIKit                               0x00000001026a6610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    40  MyApp                          0x0000000101002f1d main + 109
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010696492d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If you guys need any other information please let me know.

Comment: This can helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10095537/6124910 Maybe expects an NSString

Comment: @Patrick this answers describe the error. But I need the way out.

Comment: Your variable in your Database and the type that you send, must be the same. Both NSString or NSNumber. Whatever

Comment: If the database and object type are not same then in the first scenario mention in my question should not pass. Crash happen only for the second case.

Comment: To crosscheck I just send static values but nothing happen.

Comment: Other possibility... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186170/6124910 With this information, this is my last shot

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the link. After implement this I think the problem is in core data with multi-threading.

Comment: You´re welcome. Im going to display this post like answer and you will accept if you want. Thank you very much